# netty dependency brings old version

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, grpc, dependency-management

I am using a recent dependency of grpc-netty.
The issue is it is bringing older versions of io.netty dependencies (4.1.27)
I looked in the grpc-netty project and the used io.netty dependency version is 4.1.63.
Any idea what can be the reason for having this dependencies bring older versions of transitive dependencies?
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Post your pom.xml

Comment: Please show your full pom file... I suppose you or an other dependencies / bom is bringing it in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
         <artifactId>netty-codec-http2</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You need exclusions tag

Comment: @Elikill58, Are you able to answer this question by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104529/can-maven-run-both-cucumber-junit-and-testng-runners-together

Comment: @Theman No, sorry I'm not so strong for your question. Your question seems fine, but I don't think it's a good idea to make ad for it on other posts

Answer (score 3):

Maven does not compare version numbers when choosing a version of a dependency. It simply chooses the first version it encounters when performing a breadth-first search. For this reason, gRPC team strongly [recommends](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/1b88065f9a522cf60c7c7824c200cd55201e97a1/examples/pom.xml#L111-L128) using Maven enforcers `requireUpperBoundDeps` to let you *detect* issues like the one you face:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Then, to fix issues there are two approaches:

1. Reorder dependency list or re-define transitive dependencies
2. Use a BOM

(1) targets the breadth-first search of Maven to have the version you want to be "seen" first by Maven's search. For example, you could reorder `netty-handler` *before* `grpc-netty` in your `<dependencies>`, then Maven will encounter it first and choose its direct dependencies before `grpc-netty`'s direct dependencies. When you can't reorder to resolve issues you can add an explicit dependency on a transitive dependency to explicitly choose its version. For example, you could add `netty-resolver` with version 4.1.51.Final in your `<dependencies>`.

(2) is for multi-artifact projects like gRPC and Netty, where you really want the versions of the various artifacts to agree. You generally don't want to use `netty-buffer` 4.1.51.Final with `netty-codec-http2` 4.1.27.Final; you want them the same version. In these cases you can check whether the project has a BOM. Both [gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/1b88065f9a522cf60c7c7824c200cd55201e97a1/examples/pom.xml#L23-L33) and Netty have BOMs. With a BOM you would select the version to use once for all the various artifacts in that project. BOMs are defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` section, which is a separate section than `<dependencies>`.

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.51.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    ...
```

Whatever you do, don't exclude. Exclusions cause dependency trouble later because they hide the transitive dependencies. If a newer version of gRPC depends on a *newer* version of Netty, then you'd end up *downgrading* Netty. And at that point build tools can no longer detect or manage the problem; you'll only discover such issues at runtime.

It is clear from what you've shown that something more is going on in your pom.xml; you really need to share more of your pom to diagnose. But with the other answers telling you to exclude I wanted to show the more appropriate ways of resolving.